# Elapsed time in gdb

Tags: linux, kernel, gdb

Is there a way to measure elapsed time running the program under `gdb`?

Look to this:

```
<------------bp---------------------------------->
```

Assume that we are debugging a file and in some random place, we set a breakpoint. Now in `gdb` we perform something and then we let the program continue the execution by using the `gdb` command line (`run`).

My question is here.
I want to measure the elapsed time from the *bp* until the program either successfully ends or some error occurs.

My suggestion is to use `.gdbinit` file, and in that file we call some C function to start the timer after `run` command and at the end of the execution we also call a `gettime()` C fun.

So, my pseudo code is a bit like this (`.gdbinit` file):

```
break *0x8048452 (random place)
//start time
run
//get time
```

Comment: If your gdb has python support, you could try `python import time; starttime=time.time()` followed by `python print (time.time()-starttime)`.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick,thanks, yes you are correct. Please post your comment as an answer to mark it as a correct answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The easiest way to do this (if your gdb has python support):

```
break *0xaddress
run
# target process is now stopped at breakpoint
python import time
python starttime=time.time()
continue
python print (time.time()-starttime)
```

If your gdb doesn't have python support but can run shell commands, then use this:

```
shell echo set \$starttime=$(date +%s.%N) > ~/gdbtmp
source ~/gdbtmp
continue
shell echo print $(date +%s.%N)-\$starttime > ~/gdbtmp
source ~/gdbtmp
```

Alternatively, you could make the target process call [gettimeofday](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/gettimeofday.html) or [clock_gettime](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/clock_getres.html), but that is a lot more tedious. These functions return the time by writing to variables in the process's address space, which you'd probably have to allocate by calling something like `malloc`, and that may not work if your breakpoint stopped the program in the middle of a call to another `malloc` or `free`.

However, a slight problem with this solution is that the continue and print result lines need to be run right after each other, or else the timing will be inaccurate. We can solve this by putting the commands in a canned script through "define". If we run `define checkTime`, then gdb will prompt us to enter a list of commands. Just enter any of the command lists above(python/shell), and then you can call the script by just using the command `checkTime`. Then, the timing will be accurate. Additionally, you can put `define checkTime` and then the list of commands in the `./gdbinit` file so that you don't have to manually redefine it every time you execute a new program.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yes, I did it . but I am confused about the printed value. Is it in milliseconds or micro ?

Comment: The time is in seconds, with fractional seconds after the decimal point. The number of digits after the decimal point that are actually significant depends on the timer clock rate of your system. Clocks can be as slow as 1/60 second.

Comment: Worth noting, to get more or less accurate time representation one have to use `commands` command to make the code get executed automatically on entering the breakpoint.

Comment: @Hi-Angel Good point. The time calculations need to be done as soon as possible after the breakpoint is hit and after the program exits. Unfortunately, when executing a `commands` list attached to a breakpoint, if the list contains `continue`, any commands after it in the list won't be run. So we likely need to have the run/time-calc/continue/time-calc commands in a canned script (`source` or `define`). I will modify my answer. Thanks.